# OSX run script to mount sshfs at login with a plist file

Tags: macos, mac, launchd, plist, launchctl

I've read through the man pages for plist and launchd.plist, as well as posts about using plist files to run scripts at login; but I can seem to get things working.

My script location and permissions:

`sshfs_mounts.sh`:

```
ls -al Library/scripts/

-rwxr-xr-x   1 jason  staff   288 May 10 17:06 sshfs_mounts.sh
```

`cat Library/scripts/sshfs_mounts.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
#
## automounting of sshfs directories
mount_cosmic ()
{
    /usr/local/bin/sshfs jason@iss.nasa.gov:/media/NetworkShare/spacedock-1 /Users/jason/share;
}
mount |grep "/Users/jason/share/"
if [ $? == 1 ] && [ -d "/Users/jason/share" ] && [ $USER == "jason" ]; then
    mount_cosmic
fi
```

EDITED FROM ORIGINAL POST:

If I run the script manually, it executes as expected. I can load the plist (`launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.sshfs.plist`) and launch it (`launchctl start ~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.sshfs`), but it does not run the script. In the logs (`cat /var/log/system.log |grep local.sshfs`) I get:

```
May 11 09:30:26 rover com.apple.launchd.peruser.504[305] (local.sshfs.plist): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

Here's my location and permissions for the plist file:

```
ls -al Library/LaunchAgents/local.sshfs.plist

-rw-r--r--  1 jason  staff  419 May 10 18:14 Library/LaunchAgents/local.sshfs_mounts.plist
```

And the file (EDITED after taking Gordon's advice^2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>local.sshfs.plist</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/bin/sh</string>
            <string>/Users/jason/Library/scripts/sshfs_mounts.sh</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/sshfs_mounts.err</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/sshfs_mounts.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Mahalo in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Gordon helping me troubleshoot I was able to get the plist file properly formatted (I ended up using [plistEdit pro](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14363/plistedit-pro) because plists are picky about formatting and using a text editor didn't work for me) and determining that there was an issue in the script that I was attempting to have ran at login.

There were two things that were jamming me up. The first is that launchd was not letting my script spawn sub-process needed to mount an sshfs directory. This was fixed by adding the following key value pair:

```
<key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
<true/>
```

(thanks to tw from macworld.com's [forum post](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=105068))

Again thanks to Gordon's suggestions I was able to read errors from `/tmp/sshfs_mounts.err` to find that there was something wrong with the way my command was written. I did some searching on sshfs mounts and found information on a couple Linux sites that helped me draft a better mount command.

So here's what works.

Script:

```
mount | grep /Users/jason/share
if [ $? == 1 ] && [ -d /Users/jason/share ]; then
    /usr/local/bin/sshfs -o idmap=user jason@iss.nasa.gov:/spacedock-1 /Users/jason/share
fi
```

plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.sshfs.plist</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/jason/Library/scripts/sshfs_mounts.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know I needed the AbandonProcessGroup key.

Answer (score 5):

The "no plist was returned" error means that it was unable to parse the .plist file. I see two problems offhand: `Lable` should be `Label`, and `</true>` should be `<true/>`. You can use the command `plutil -lint ~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.sshfs_mounts.plist` to check the plist syntax, although it will not detect whether the data in the plist is valid as a launchd item.

Comment: your post was most helpful. The plist file is now loading without issue, and I can start it with `lanchctl`. I'll post my edited code. The issue now is every time I start the plist file it fails and I get the following in the `system.log`: `Exited with code: 127`

Comment: Exit status 127 generally means command not found -- is the sshfs command in one of the standard PATH directories, or in one you add in your e.g. .bash_profile? If that's the problem, either specify its full path in the script (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/sshfs jason@...`) or set PATH appropriately in the script. If that's not the problem, try capturing the script's output by adding `<key>StandardOutPath</key><string>/tmp/sshfs_mounts.out</string><key>StandardErrorPath</key><string>/tmp/sshfs_mounts.err</string>` to the .plist file, and see if that illuminates the problem.

Comment: you help me get rid of all the errors, but the script still does not run. I changed the script as you suggested, also redirected the output. I get nothing into `sshfs.out` or `sshfs.err`. Moreover the output to `/var/log/system.log` is `Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds`. Example code updated.

Comment: I just noticed you have `KeepAlive` set to `<true/>`, meaning that if the script exits for any reason, launchd will restart it. Does `sshfs` exit after mounting the server? If so (or if the `if` statement isn't executed), this means launchd will run the script over & over, although it throttles the relaunch rate to every 10 seconds. Other than that, is the script successfully mounting the server? If not, you should add some "echo" commands to give debugging output so you can figure out what's wrong?